# Expectation of a function of normal random variable is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose that we have

$E [f(Ma+x)] = c^Ta $, for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^d$

where $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n,d}$ is fixed, $c \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is fixed, and $x$ is a normal random variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2 I$. Is it possible to prove that function $f$ must be linear to satisfy the above equation, i.e. $f(y) = l^T y$?

Comment: What do you know in the case $n=d=1$?

Comment: @kimchilover I'm not sure how to show that even in the case where we have $n = d = 1$. I tried using Taylor series expansion of $f$ (assuming that it has a Taylor series expansion) and then taking expectations over moments of normal rv $x$. In that case, it seems that we have a non-linear function of $a$ equal to a linear function $a$. But this seems handwavy to me.

Comment: I would reduce this  problem to $E(g(x+a)=0$ for all $a$, some function related  to $f$.